# Barriers seems to synchronize only within a time window

Tags: synchronization, opencl, barrier

currently I tried to implement the FDTD-Method to solve the Maxwell equations
using OpenCL. The algorithm is pretty simple, calculate the current h-field
from the old electric field and calculate the current e-field from the current h-field. Than start the next iteration. In OpenCL synchronisation issues occur
as the e-field cant be calculated before the h-field was calculated and the next iteration has to be started synchronously. Therefor only one workgroup has to be used. I ensure this by making the global and lokal work space the same size.
My gpu has a max work item value of 256, this means for a 3d problem space I can have 6 workitems in every dimension. Thats why every workitem calculates a cube of field values. The problem that I encounter is that the algorithm yields correct results for as long as every workitem calculates less than 12 field values in every dimension, 1728 field values in total.
If the workitems have to calculate more field values the results of the algorithm gets worse and worse. I tested the algorithm with double precision floating points as well which yielded even worse results.
My suspicion assured by the double precision results is, that the calculation of all field values needs to much time and the synchronisation does not work properly anymore. Here is the source code of the OpenCL kernel:

```
    kernel void fdtd3d_noiter_fp32(
                   global float3* old_e,
                   global float3* old_h,
                   global float3* current_e,
                   global float3* current_h,
                   global float3* e_curl_integral,
                   global float3* e_field_integral,
                   global float3* h_curl_integral,
                   global float3* h_field_integral,
                   constant float4* ex_factor,
                   constant float4* ey_factor,
                   constant float4* ez_factor,
                   constant float4* hx_factor,
                   constant float4* hy_factor,
                   constant float4* hz_factor,
                   constant char* geometry,
                   float grid_width_x,
                   float grid_width_y,
                   float grid_width_z,
                   int uwidth,
                   int udepth,
                   float max_time,
                   float time_step,
                   int batch_size_x,
                   int batch_size_y,
                   int batch_size_z,
                   constant char* source_factor,
                   float source_amplitude,
                   float source_ramp_len,
                   float source_frequency)
{
// get the actual id
    const int  ID = get_global_id(0) * batch_size_x + get_global_id(1) * batch_size_y * uwidth + get_global_id(2) * batch_size_z * uwidth * udepth + 1 + uwidth + uwidth * udepth;
```

`int id = ID;

for (float current_time = 0; current_time < max_time; current_time += time_step)
{
    for (int z = 0; z < batch_size_z; z++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < batch_size_y; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < batch_size_x; x++)
            {
                id = ID + x + y * uwidth + z * uwidth * udepth;
                // calculate the current magnetic field from the old electric field
                float hx_curl_term = ((old_e[id + uwidth].z - old_e[id].z) / grid_width_y) - ((old_e[id + uwidth * udepth].y - old_e[id].y) / grid_width_z);
                float hy_curl_term = ((old_e[id + uwidth * udepth].x - old_e[id].x) / grid_width_z) - ((old_e[id + 1].z - old_e[id].z) / grid_width_x);
                float hz_curl_term = ((old_e[id + 1].y - old_e[id].y) / grid_width_x) - ((old_e[id + uwidth].x - old_e[id].x) / grid_width_y);
                h_curl_integral[id].x += hx_curl_term;
                h_curl_integral[id].y += hy_curl_term;
                h_curl_integral[id].z += hz_curl_term;
                h_field_integral[id] += old_h[id];
                current_h[id].x = + hx_factor[id].x * old_h[id].x - hx_factor[id].y * hx_curl_term
                         - hx_factor[id].z * h_curl_integral[id].x - hx_factor[id].w * h_field_integral[id].x;
                current_h[id].y = + hy_factor[id].x * old_h[id].y - hy_factor[id].y * hy_curl_term
                         - hy_factor[id].z * h_curl_integral[id].y - hy_factor[id].w * h_field_integral[id].y;
                current_h[id].z = + hz_factor[id].x * old_h[id].z - hz_factor[id].y * hz_curl_term
                         - hz_factor[id].z * h_curl_integral[id].z - hz_factor[id].w * h_field_integral[id].z;
            }
        }
    }

    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE | CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

    // calculate the current electric field from the current magnetic field
    for (int z = 0; z < batch_size_z; z++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < batch_size_y; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < batch_size_x; x++)
            {
                id = ID + x + y * uwidth + z * uwidth * udepth;
                float ex_curl_term = ((current_h[id].z - current_h[id - uwidth].z) / grid_width_y) - ((current_h[id].y - current_h[id - uwidth * udepth].y) / grid_width_z);
                float ey_curl_term = ((current_h[id].x - current_h[id - uwidth * udepth].x) / grid_width_z) - ((current_h[id].z - current_h[id - 1].z) / grid_width_x);
                float ez_curl_term = ((current_h[id].y - current_h[id - 1].y) / grid_width_x) - ((current_h[id].x - current_h[id - uwidth].x) / grid_width_y);
                e_curl_integral[id].x += ex_curl_term;
                e_curl_integral[id].y += ey_curl_term;
                e_curl_integral[id].z += ez_curl_term;
                e_field_integral[id] += old_e[id];
                current_e[id].x = ex_factor[id].x * old_e[id].x - ex_factor[id].y * e_field_integral[id].x
                         + ex_factor[id].z * ex_curl_term + ex_factor[id].w * e_curl_integral[id].x;
                current_e[id].y = ey_factor[id].x * old_e[id].y - ey_factor[id].y * e_field_integral[id].y
                         + ey_factor[id].z * ey_curl_term + ey_factor[id].w * e_curl_integral[id].y;
                current_e[id].z = ez_factor[id].x * old_e[id].z - ez_factor[id].y * e_field_integral[id].z
                         + ez_factor[id].z * ez_curl_term + ez_factor[id].w * e_curl_integral[id].z;

                // zero ez out if the soure_factor is 1
                current_e[id].z -= abs(source_factor[id]) * current_e[id].z;
                // than add the source. this way a hard source is created!
                current_e[id].z += source_factor[id] * source_amplitude * ramped_sin_fp32(current_time, source_ramp_len, source_frequency);
                current_e[id] *= geometry[id];
            }
        }
    }

    // synchronize the workitems after calculating the current fields
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE | CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

    // now memory consistency is assured and the fields can be copied
    for (int z = 0; z < batch_size_z; z++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < batch_size_y; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < batch_size_x; x++)
            {
                id = ID + x + y * uwidth + z * uwidth * udepth;
                old_h[id] = current_h[id];
                old_e[id] = current_e[id];
            }
        }
    }
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE | CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
}`

}

I hope the code is not to unintelligible and someone can help me!

lyding

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with the small things:

> barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE

Using local barrier makes no sense if you don't use local variables.

> My suspicion assured by the double precision results is, that the calculation of all field values needs to much time and the synchronisation does not work properly anymore

synchronization in GPU is done by the hardware, and while possible, it's unlikely the problem.

Now the big problem:

> In OpenCL synchronisation issues occur as the e-field cant be
>   calculated before the h-field was calculated and the next iteration
>   has to be started synchronously. Therefor only one workgroup has to be
>   used. I ensure this by making the global and lokal work space the same size.

... and that's an absolute no-go. You're essentially serializing your code. This will both kill the performance and have awful GPU utilization, and likely run slower than on CPU.

I haven't looked closely at your code, but it's possible (AFAICT) you don't have to use a single workgroup. The way i'd write it (pseudocode):

OpenCL code:

```
kernel1(arguments) { calculate the current magnetic field from the old electric field }
kernel2(arguments) { calculate the current electric field from the current magnetic field }
kernel3(arguments) { copy current to old (both e/h) }
```

Host code:

```
for (float current_time = 0; current_time < max_time; current_time += time_step)
   {
       clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel1, ...);
       clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel2, ...);
       clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel3, ...);
   }
```

Whether this is a good idea, depends.. on a lot of things - problem size, timestep etc. But it would allow you to use 3D grid for global work, and the GPU would run these in parallel. Perhaps try to find some OpenCL or CUDA code on github that calculates Maxwell equations.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my code in detail, I will rewrite my code like you suggested even if I stay curious what causes this behavior.